# Unification and Inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Have you ever wondered why there exists a mathematical symbol for the unification of sets but not for the inclusion of sets, concerning nested intervals for example?

Let $(X_{i})_{{i}\in{I}}$ be a family of sets ($I=\left\{ {1,...,k}\right\}$).  By ZFC, this family defines another set $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} X_{i}$

But if we want to say that the sets are included in each other (with $X_{m}$ as the "largest" set if $m=min\left\{ {1,...,k}\right\}$) we have to write it down entirely like $X_{k}\subset X_{k-1} \subset.......\subset X_{m}$

Why isn't there a simple symbol which shows this connection among sets? Let's call it "general inclusion".

We might consider defining it as $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} X_{i+1}\setminus X_{i}$, then, if $X_{b+1}\subset X_{b}$ for all $b\in {I}$, the general inclusion is empty. 
So, the emptiness or non-emptiness of the general inclusion could be viewed as kind of a boolean value.

Could this be useful in any way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. What's wrong with saying that $(X_i \mid i \in I)$ is a $\subseteq$-increasing sequence? (Assuming that the order on $I$ is obvious in this context.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, my problem was that I think that this isn't defined as elegantly as it could be. I mean, there is no purely mathematical expression for it. I wanted to define a property of $(X_{i})_{{i}\in{I}}$ which is purely set-theoretic and could determine whether it is ⊆-increasing or not.  If I am on the "Holzweg", please excuse, I am just a first semester student.

Answer (score 1):

For finite $I \subseteq \mathbb N$ we have that $(X_i \mid i \in I)$ is $\subseteq$-increasing if and only if $\bigcup_{i \in (I \setminus \max I)} X_i \setminus X_{i+1} = \emptyset$. (You seem to have it backwards in your post and you have in integer out of bounds in there.)

This is due to the simple fact that $X_i \subseteq X_{i+1} \iff X_{i} \setminus X_{i+1} = \emptyset$ and that the operator $\bigcup$ is $\subseteq$-monotone.

> Could this be useful in any way?

Probably but it's not worth thinking about such possible situations too much. This equivalence is so simple that, if there were a situation to arise in which it was useful, everyone encountering that situation will likely think of this fact more or less automatically. (It's a bit like the set-theoretic equivalent of multiplying both sides of a given equation by some invertible constant.)

Comment: I see. So my attempt to formalize ⊆-increasing families of sets was kind of trivial.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy I realize that my answer (despite rephrasing it) is a bit demotivating and that's not my goal in the slightest. It's a nice observation and a good exercise -- especially if you are still getting used to set theory. But it's also very basic and hence doesn't merit a lot of further discussion (i.e. there is nothing much more to be said about this equivalence), I think.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy Btw, if you want a more challenging problem in the same spirit: What if $(X_i \mid i \in I)$ is indexed by $I = \mathbb R$. $(X_i \mid i \in \mathbb R)$ is (per definition) $\subseteq$-increasing iff for all $i,j \in \mathbb R \colon i  \le j \implies X_i \subseteq X_j$. Now there are many indices between $i$ and $i+1$. Can you still come up with a similar characterization? What if $(I; \le)$ is a general [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)?

Comment: Maybe $\forall\epsilon>0$:$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} X_{i+\epsilon }\setminus X_{i}=\varnothing $ ?

Comment: That almost works. You reversed the role of $X_{i+\epsilon}$ and $X_i$ again, $\bigcup_{i=1}^k$ doesn't make any sense in this context and you can rewrite it more clearly to $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb R} \bigcup_{\epsilon > 0}  X_{i} \setminus X_{i + \epsilon} = \emptyset$. A very similar formula works for general total orders.

Comment: Oh yeah, forget about the $\bigcup_{i=1}^k$ thing, I just copied it from my other posts and forgot to erase those indices.